# Prevent link from redirecting to another page in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-ui

I am new to react js

I have created a tile in reactjs. Tile has star button(favourite) inside it. Both tile & star button are clickable. when user clicks on tile it navigates to next page.On click of star icon, it should only change the status of tile to favourite , it is doing that, but also navigates to next page. i want to prevent it from navigating to next page. Please see the code below

**My file extension is .jsx**

I am user material UI controls. The below code has box control , inside box has link control, i tried
event.preventDefault() & assigning "#" for link. but it is not working

```
  let isFavToggleClicked = false;
      let disableLink = false;
    
     const handleFavouriteToggle = (event) => {
        isFavToggleClicked = true;
    
      }
    
      const handleTileClick = (event) => {
    
        if (isFavToggleClicked ) {
          event.preventDefault();
          disableLink = true;
        }
        }
      }
    
      const preventDefault = (event) => event.preventDefault();
    
      return (
         <Box
      className={disableLink ? "project-tile-box disabled-link" : "project-tile-box"}
      onClick={disableLink ? preventDefault : handleTileClick}
    >

      <Link
        to={
        disableLink
            ? '#' : '/project/details/' + project.projectId
        }
        className={disableLink ? "disabled-link" : ''}

        onClick={disableLink ? preventDefault : ''}
      >
        <Card className={borderColor}>
          <CardContent>
            <Box>
              <Box display="flex" pb={1}>
                <Box mr={0.5} flexGrow={1}>
                  <Tooltip title={project.projectName}>
                    <Typography
                      variant="h6"
                      className="header-three"
                    >
                    {Name}
                    </Typography>
                  </Tooltip>
                </Box>
                <Box mr={0.5}>
                  <Tooltip title={Test}>
                    <Chip
                      size="small"
                      label={"businessPractice"}
                    />
                  </Tooltip>
                </Box>
                
                <Box>
                  <Tooltip title="Pin Project">
                    <IconButton
                      onClick={handleFavouriteToggle }
                    >
                      {
                        project.isPinned
                          ? <StarSharp className="task-tile-icon" />
                          : <StarBorderOutlined className="task-tile-icon" />
                      }
                    </IconButton>
                  </Tooltip>
                </Box>
              </Box>
              
               </CardContent>
        </Card>
```

Please find below how the tile looks.

[image: Tile]

How can prevent a link from redirecting to another page ?,Could you please help on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think we need more information before we can help you. For instance I'm seeing the declaration of handleFavouriteToggle but nowhere is it being used

Comment: Why don't you just do something like disableLink ? <p>Name</p>  : <Link>{Name}</Link> and just style your p tag to look like a disabled link, there's no disabled property for the link so I guess this is what makes more sense if you don't want to link to a different page.

Comment: @bryanstevens314 , I have updated the code with handleFavouriteToggle  event. My bad missed while posting

Answer (score 0):

It is because  `<Link>/* content */</Link>` content is inside anchor tag (Link).

You have to remove STAR icon outside the Link tag

```
  <Link
        to={
        disableLink
            ? '#' : '/project/details/' + project.projectId
        }
        className={disableLink ? "disabled-link" : ''}

        onClick={disableLink ? preventDefault : ''}
      >
        <Card className={borderColor}>
          <CardContent>
            <Box>
              <Box display="flex" pb={1}>
                <Box mr={0.5} flexGrow={1}>
                  <Tooltip title={project.projectName}>
                    <Typography
                      variant="h6"
                      className="header-three"
                    >
                    {Name}
                    </Typography>
                  </Tooltip>
                </Box>
                <Box mr={0.5}>
                  <Tooltip title={Test}>
                    <Chip
                      size="small"
                      label=businessPractice
                    />
                  </Tooltip>
                </Box>
        </CardContent>
       </Card>
    </Link>
```